# clarification of a doubt over a defined result in ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was going through the topic of **Wronskian** in ODE came up with the following result:

[image]

I have a little doubt. Can we say the same if we interchange $y_1$  and $y_2$ i.e. between consecutive zeroes of $y_2$ there is exactly one zero of $y_1$. Or, between successive zeroes of $y_1~(or~y_2)$ there is exactly one zero of $y_2~(or~y_1$)
Kindly help.

Comment: This is so interesting. Now that I think about it, every oscillatory solution to second order equations I can think of satisfy this condition. Probably has to do with $\cos$ and $\sin$ being the linearly independent functions for oscillations.

Comment: Yes, you can say the same thing for $y_2$ and $y_1$.

Comment: @KittyL thanks :)